# Percolate query in Azure Search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

ElasticSearch has a very [convenient feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-percolate-query.html) that allows you to store queries in your index and match a document against them. This is useful when you implement something like Google Alerts. Does Azure Search have similar functionality? If not, what people use instead?